# How to return NULL value is no records are found in multiple join conditions

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a report where i need to show all Purchase Indents as per filters and corresponding purchase lines of these indent lines.
If there is no purchase line found as per my condition then it should return NULL value. But report is not showing Indents for which there are no records in purchase lines.
I'm joining 4 tables - INH,INL,PL,PH. The Query is shown below.

```
SELECT
    INH.No_
    ,INH.[Approved Date]
    ,INH.Indentor
    ,INL.No_ AS ItemCode
    ,INL.description
    ,INL.Description2
    ,INL.Req_Quantity
    ,INL.[Unit of Measure]
    ,PL.[Document No_]
    ,PH.[Order Date]
    ,PL.Quantity AS OrderedQuantity
    ,PL.[Quantity Received]
FROM [ICTL | HYDERABAD$Indent Header] AS INH
INNER JOIN [ICTL | HYDERABAD$Indent Line] AS INL ON INH.No_ = INL.[Document No_]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ICTL | HYDERABAD$Purchase Line] AS PL ON INL.[Document No_] = PL.[Indent No_] AND INL.[Line No_] = PL.[Indent Line No_]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ICTL | HYDERABAD$Purchase Header] AS PH ON PL.[Document No_] = PH.No_
WHERE (UPPER(INH.Indentor) = UPPER(@Name)
    OR @Name IS NULL)
    AND (INL.No_ <> '')
    AND (INH.[Approved Date] >= @StartDate
    OR @StartDate IS NULL)
    AND (INH.[Approved Date] <= @EndDate
    OR @EndDate IS NULL)
    AND (PL.[Document Type] = 1)
ORDER BY ItemCode
```

Comment: Your query is too verbose for either yourself or anyone here to clearly understand.  (The repetition of filters is a big red-flag for me, as are your table names which seem very irregular for SQL server)  Consider creating a SQLfiddle with example schema and data.

Comment: Yeah, i understand. below is the query. Please check.

Comment: Query is edited. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are have `PL.[Document Type] = 1` in your query.  This will automatically exclude all rows where there is no PL record (your `OUTER JOIN` does not matter then).

Either you'd have to do `PL.[Document Type] IS NULL OR PL.[Document Type] = 1` in the `WHERE` clause, or you'd have to add the  `PL.[Document Type] = 1` to the `JOIN` condition of the `PL` table.

Answer (score 1):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT
      INH.No_
    , INH.[Approved Date]
    , INH.Indentor
    , INL.No_ AS ItemCode
    , INL.description
    , INL.Description2
    , INL.Req_Quantity
    , INL.[Unit of Measure]
    , PL.[Document No_]
    , PH.[Order Date]
    , PL.Quantity AS OrderedQuantity
    , PL.[Quantity Received]
FROM [ICTL | HYDERABAD$Indent Header] INH
JOIN [ICTL | HYDERABAD$Indent Line] INL ON INH.No_ = INL.[Document No_]
LEFT JOIN [ICTL | HYDERABAD$Purchase Line] PL ON INL.[Document No_] = PL.[Indent No_] AND INL.[Line No_] = PL.[Indent Line No_]
LEFT JOIN [ICTL | HYDERABAD$Purchase Header] PH ON PL.[Document No_] = PH.No_
WHERE UPPER(INH.Indentor) = UPPER(ISNULL(@Name, INH.Indentor))
    AND INL.No_ <> ''
    AND INH.[Approved Date] BETWEEN ISNULL(@StartDate, '19000101') AND ISNULL(@EndDate, '30000101')
    AND ISNULL(PL.[Document Type], 1) = 1
ORDER BY ItemCode
```

Comment: No, the result is same. I'd like to explain it more efficiently. I have purchase indents No's PIN-0338,PIN-0339,PIN-0341 where 339 & 341 are converted into purchase orders but 338 is not yet converted. In my report i would like to show all indents and their purchase orders. If there is no Purchase order for any indent then that should be displayed as blank. But, here 338 is not getting displayed and rest 2 are shown in report.